# Having trouble assigning different variables in the main module for an assignment I have

Tags: python

```
def GetEmpName():
    empName = input("Enter employee name: ")
    return empName
#write the GetHoursWorked function
def GetHoursWorked():
    hrsWrkd = input("Enter hours worked: ")
    return hrsWrkd

#write the GetHourlyRate function
def GetHourlyRate():
    hrlyRate = input("Enter hourly rate: ")
    return hrlyRate

# write the GetTaxRate function
def GetTaxRate():
    taxRate = input("Enter Tax Rate: ")
    return taxRate



def CalcTaxAndNetPay(hrsWrkd, hrlyRate, taxRate):
    grosspay = hrsWrkd * hrlyRate
    incometax = grosspay * taxRate
    netpay = grosspay - incometax
    return grosspay, incometax, netpay

def printinfo(empName, hrsWrkd, hrlyRate, grosspay, taxRate, incometax, netpay):
    print(empname, f"{hrsWrkd:,.2f}",  f"{hrlyRate:,.2f}", f"{grosspay:,.2f}",  f"{taxRate:,.1%}",  f"{incometax:,.2f}",  f"{netpay:,.2f}")

def PrintTotals(TotEmployees, TotHours, TotGrossPay, TotTax, TotNetPay):    
    print()
    print(f"Total Number Of Employees: {TotEmployees}")
    # write the code to print TotHours, TotGrossPay, TotTax, and TotNetpay with 2 decimal places
    print(f"Total number of hours: {TotHours}.2.f")
    print(f"Total gross pay: {TotGrossPay},.2f")
    print(f"Total tax: {TotTax},.2f")
    print(f"Total net pay: {TotNetpay},.2f")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TotEmployees = 0
    TotHours = 0.00
    TotGrossPay = 0.00
    TotTax = 0.00
    TotNetPay = 0.00
    while True:
        empName = GetEmpName()
        if (empName.upper() == "END"):
            break
        # write the code to assign to hours the return value from GetHoursWorked
        GetHoursWorked = hrsWrked
        # write the code to assign to hourlyrate the return value from GetHourlyRate
        GetHourlyRate = hrlyRate
        # write the code to assign to taxrate the return value from GetTaxRate
        GetTaxRate = taxRate
        grosspay, incometax, netpay = CalcTaxAndNetPay(hrsWrkd, hrlyRate, taxRate)
        printinfo(empName, hrsWrkd, hrlyRate, grosspay, taxRate, incometax, netpay)
        TotEmployees += 1
        # write the code to increment the other total variables with the appropriate values



PrintTotals (TotEmployees, TotHours, TotGrossPay, TotTax, TotNetPay)
```

This is for an assignment and I'm having trouble with the main module in calling the functions. I'm a bit lost of what the next code that needs to be included for it to run properly.

Comment: Which trouble do you have with calling the functions?

Comment: Are you asking why `PrintTotals` isn't called?

Comment: Its under the __main__ module that I'm not sure what to code. The comments that I have under there are what the assignment is calling for. So the GetHourlyRate = hrlyRate is something I'm guessing and I know isn't correct.

Comment: do you mean in the body of the the `if __nam__ == "__main__": ...` conditional? You really need to provide an adequate explanation of the problem you are having exactly. Since you are new here, make sure to check out the [help] and [ask]

Comment: What did your learning materials say about how to call a function and store its return value in a variable? Why could you do it with `GetEmpName()` but not with `GetHoursWorked`?

Comment: Well this would allow for multiple inputs for how ever many employees there are and if there are no more entries END would be input and the loop would end. I'm guessing at this point at what I would need to put to follow.

Answer (score 0):

After copying in your code and working through some syntax and indentation issues, I did a bit of code cleanup and correction to the code to allow for the entry of one or more employee time information.  Following is a revised version of the code.

```
def GetEmpName():
    empName = input("Enter employee name: ")
    return empName
    
#write the GetHoursWorked function

def GetHoursWorked():
    hrsWrkd = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
    return hrsWrkd

#write the GetHourlyRate function

def GetHourlyRate():
    hrlyRate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
    return hrlyRate

# write the GetTaxRate function

def GetTaxRate():
    taxRate = float(input("Enter Tax Rate: "))
    return taxRate

def CalcTaxAndNetPay(hrsWrkd, hrlyRate, taxRate):
    grosspay = hrsWrkd * hrlyRate
    incometax = grosspay * taxRate
    netpay = grosspay - incometax
    return grosspay, incometax, netpay

def printinfo(empName, hrsWrkd, hrlyRate, grosspay, taxRate, incometax, netpay):
    print(empName, f"{hrsWrkd:,.2f}",  f"{hrlyRate:,.2f}", f"{grosspay:,.2f}",  f"{taxRate:,.1%}",  f"{incometax:,.2f}",  f"{netpay:,.2f}")

def PrintTotals(TotEmployees, TotHours, TotGrossPay, TotTax, TotNetPay):    
    print()
    print(f"Total Number Of Employees: {TotEmployees}")
    # write the code to print TotHours, TotGrossPay, TotTax, and TotNetpay with 2 decimal places
    print(f"Total number of hours: {TotHours}.2.f")
    print(f"Total gross pay: {TotGrossPay},.2f")
    print(f"Total tax: {TotTax},.2f")
    print(f"Total net pay: {TotNetPay},.2f")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TotEmployees = 0
    TotHours = 0.00
    TotGrossPay = 0.00
    TotTax = 0.00
    TotNetPay = 0.00
    while True:
        empName = GetEmpName()
        if empName.upper() == "END":
            break
        # write the code to assign to hours the return value from GetHoursWorked
        hrsWrkd = GetHoursWorked()  # Swapped the order of variable and function call
        TotHours += hrsWrkd
        # write the code to assign to hourlyrate the return value from GetHourlyRate
        hrlyRate = GetHourlyRate()  # Swapped the order of variable and function call
        # write the code to assign to taxrate the return value from GetTaxRate
        taxRate = GetTaxRate()      # Swapped the order of variable and function call
        grosspay, incometax, netpay = CalcTaxAndNetPay(hrsWrkd, hrlyRate, taxRate)
        TotGrossPay += grosspay
        TotTax += incometax
        TotNetPay += netpay
        printinfo(empName, hrsWrkd, hrlyRate, grosspay, taxRate, incometax, netpay)
        TotEmployees += 1
        # write the code to increment the other total variables with the appropriate values

    PrintTotals (TotEmployees, TotHours, TotGrossPay, TotTax, TotNetPay)
```

Following, are some points to note.

- Where you had statements written to evidently store hourly rates, hours worked, taxes, and so forth, the statements were corrected so that the variable that was supposed to contain the values was to the left of the equals sign and the associated function call that would return the needed value was to the right of the equals sign.
- Also, with the correction of the variable and function call order, any missing parentheses were added to the function call.
- Input data that needed to be a floating point value were noted by adding the "float" qualifier in front of the "input" statements; otherwise, the value returned from the functions would be a string causing a program failure.
- Also care was taken to ensure that all of the proper upper and lower case letters were used for the variables as Python variables are case sensitive.

With those bits noted, a test of the revised program was run to ensure its basic functions worked.

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Employee$ python3 Employee.py 
Enter employee name: John
Enter hours worked: 40.00
Enter hourly rate: 32.00
Enter Tax Rate: .15
John 40.00 32.00 1,280.00 15.0% 192.00 1,088.00
Enter employee name: Jane
Enter hours worked: 40.00
Enter hourly rate: 38.00
Enter Tax Rate: .15
Jane 40.00 38.00 1,520.00 15.0% 228.00 1,292.00
Enter employee name: END

Total Number Of Employees: 2
Total number of hours: 80.0.2.f
Total gross pay: 2800.0,.2f
Total tax: 420.0,.2f
Total net pay: 2380.0,.2f
```

Give that a try to see if that meets the spirit of your project.